# Permissions and owners of /system/etc/hosts

Tags: root-access

Can somebody please tell me what permissions, owner & group I should give to /system/etc/hosts file? My current script is:

```
#!/system/bin/sh
ln -s /system/etc /etc
touch /etc/hosts
chmod 644 /etc/hosts
chown root:root /etc/hosts
echo "IPADDR DOMAIN" >> /etc/hosts
svc data disable
svc data enable
```

Can someone help me with the following?

```
chmod 644 /etc/hosts
chown root:root /etc/hosts
```

Comment: This is from my rooted phone running Cyanogenmod 11: `-rw-r--r-- root     root           25 2008-08-01 08:00 hosts`

Answer (score 1):

Those are the correct permissions and owner/group for hosts.

Beyond that, you would need to add additional information to your question for further assistance.